# Load page specific resource(s) using @include

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.3

How do I load page specific resource(s) using **`@include`** of the Laravel blade template engine?

Below is the content of my *Master* layout (**`master.blade.php`**):

```
<head>
    @section('styles')
        {{-- Some Master Styles --}}
    @show
</head>
<body>
    {{-- Header --}}
    @section('header')
        @include('header')
    @show

    {{-- Content --}} 
    @section('content')
        {{-- Content for page is extending this view --}}
    @show

    {{-- Footer --}}
    @section('footer')
        @include('footer')
    @show
</body>
```

In a given page, I make use of my master template this way:

```
@extends('master')

@section('styles')
    @parent
    {{-- Page Stylesheet --}}
@endsection
```

The approach above is what I use to try and load my page specific style to the `<head>` section.

It does not work properly as expected.

I would like to as well load other page specific resource(s) in my footer using the same approach; how can I do that effectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do

```
@extends('master')

@section('styles')
    @parent
    {{-- Page Stylesheet --}}
@endsection
```

in your respective pages so as to load page specific stylesheets.

You should rather load page specific stylesheets for your **`master.blade.php`** file so as to keep your code dry.

To to that, you shout specify the route or expected url format of such pages, then, the appropriate stylesheet(s) to be loaded.

You can do that this way in your **`master.blade.php`** file:

```
@section('styles')
    @if(Request::is('transactions/generate-invoice'))
        @include('generate-invoice-css')
    @elseif(Request::is('transactions/users'))
        @include('users-css')
    @endif
@show
```

Where **`generate-invoice-css.blade.php`** contains the stylesheet(s) you want loaded for the page content accessible at **`yoursite.com/transactions/generate-invoice`** and **`users-css.blade.php`**, that of **`yoursite.com/transactions/users`**.

For a given pattern as in: *same stylesheets for pages under `transactions`*, you can do this:

```
@if(Request::is('transactions*'))
```

*using a wildcard **`*`***.

To load a given resource to a location other than the `<head>` section of your pages, simply use the same approach and adapt as appropriate.

To load page specific resources with an **`@include()`** from your **`master.blade.php`**, use this approach *(in your **`master.blade.php`** file)*:

```
@section('styles')
    @include('styles')
@show
```

where **`styles.blade.php`** should contain those your conditions for the appropriate resources to be loaded satisfying your requirement(s) for the purpose as in:

```
@if(Request::is('transactions/generate-invoice'))
    @include('generate-invoice-css')
@elseif(Request::is('transactions/users'))
    @include('users-css')
@endif
```

As the content of your **`styles.blade.php`**.

Comment: Thanks @nyedidikeke for the response. As far as the including, I added it within a section because there will be more in the _Master_ that contributes to it.

As for the loading of the stylesheet as you mentioned, this works, but it ads the stylesheet inline. I was hoping there was a "cleaner" way to go about it where it would add the stylesheet to the head as it does with extensions of the layout when they load styles.

This may not be an option, but I'm trying to find out if it is at all possible.

Comment: Then you should include it in your **`styles.blade.php`** if you want it in your `<head>` section. Based on your question, you expressed including it your your *footer* section.

Comment: Updated my answer based on your submission above, to include your stylesheets in the `<head>` section instead.

Comment: Ok, I guess I just didn't pose my question clearly. I was hoping that each view could load it's own stylesheet. For example, when the footer is included it imports its own stylesheet, but the blade template places the <link> with the rest of the stylesheet imports in the <head>. This seems to be what happens when a page extends a layout and loads a stylesheet.

Comment: You're recent comments suggest, perhaps, that is just not the correct approach from what I understand. Once again, thank you for the help!

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit further? I do not understand what you meant in your last comment above. The best location for your stylesheets is the `<head>` section of your HTML file and as such. In your question, you expressed including it in your footer instead which was what I've earlier submitted, but re-edited as you re-expressed doing it a cleaner way, in your `<head>` section. Is there something you feel not addressed or that I did not get well?

Comment: I appreciate your patience on this. I have revised the original question to further elaborate. I hope this provides clarity.

Comment: Updated my answer based on your clarifications.

Comment: I appreciate your advice. I see what you're saying. Thank you.